# Fourier transform of the tempered distribution $\frac{1}{|x|^{n-1}}$ with cutoff

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

According to wikipedia, the fourier transform of $\frac{1}{|x|^{n-1}}$ is $C\frac{1}{|\xi|^1}$, or more generally the fourier transform of $\frac{1}{|x|^{n-k}}$ is $C\frac{1}{|\xi|^k}$ for $0 < k <  n$.

I have no idea why that is true but let's take that for granted for now, now suppose I multiply $\frac{1}{|x|^{-n+1}}$ by a compactly supported smooth function that is supported near the origin, then since the tempered distribution is $L^1$ (say $n>1$), the fourier transform of this will then actually be a smooth function, in other word the singularity of $\frac{1}{|\xi|}$ at the origin should get smoothed out somehow.

This seems to be consistent with something my professors have said, that fourier transform takes growth at infinity to growth at zero, and vice versa, however is there a theorem somewhere that makes this statement formal? Preferably one that address how the singularity at zero gets removed on the frequency side by multiplying a compactly supported function on the spatial side?

Comment: While I may be missing something from your question, I think [this post might help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320631/smoothness-of-fourier-transform-of-frac1xp?rq=1).

Comment: The Fourier transform of function with compact support is an Analytical function (due Paley–Wiener theorem). But for the growth part I think maybe you are looking for the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: @Joako Thanks for the response, I think what I'm trying to do is get the fourier transform of the above in terms of the fourier transform of $\frac{1}{|x|^{n-1}}$,  I tried using convolution theorem but to avail.

Comment: Let me suggest you been more explicit with what you want to ask, as example, from the title I think you are askiing for $$\int_{-a}^{a}\dfrac{e^{-i\xi x}}{|x|^{n-1}}\ dx$$ for some $a>0$, but instead what I understand for the text is that you are looking to solve $$\int_{--\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\varphi(x)\ e^{-i\xi x}}{|x|^{n-1}}\ dx$$ for some smooth compact suported function $\varphi(x)$ (like $$\varphi(x)=\begin{cases}0,\ |x|\geq 1,\\ \exp\left(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2-1}\right),\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ as example), and both are very different questions

Comment: The convolution of a function $u$ by a smooth quickly decaying function is smooth and has approximately the same decay as $u$.